# Constantly getting insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost

Tags: hardhat

Im trying to write some basic contract to the mainnet.
On Ropsten everthing went smoothly but on mainnet i constantly getting the aforementioned error
Im using the ETH guide on: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/how-to-write-and-deploy-an-nft/

The wallet attached has ~ 0.7 ETH.
I have tried playing with hardhat gas & gasprice setting but with no succes.

The code

```
async function main() {
  const MyNFT = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyPRODNFT")
  const myNFT = await MyNFT.deploy()
  console.log("Contract deployed to address:", myNFT.address)
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
    process.exit(1)
  })
```

the hardhat.config.js

```
/**
* @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
*/
require('dotenv').config();
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
require("hardhat-gas-reporter");

const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;
module.exports = {
   solidity: "0.8.0",
   defaultNetwork: "eth",
   networks: {
      hardhat: {},
      eth: {
         url: API_URL,
         accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`],
  gas: 95000000000, //*95 Gwei OR 95,000,000,000 wei

          
      },
   },
}
```

Comment: Check your config file `gas` (no unit) is not the same as `gasPrice` (unit is wei).

Comment: What a suitable config is? (it's also not working with auto-auto config & with other values) I can only set transactions of up to 25gwei

Comment: Also. The documention of hardhat suggest they are interchangeable

Comment: That's not accurate it says [*This parameter behaves like gas*](https://hardhat.org/config/#json-rpc-based-networks). Probably it means the "auto" keyword behaves similarly. The `gas` parameter is how many execution unit you are willing to pay, it is around 30M (30x10^6) in mainnet and rinkeby. The `gasPrice` is how much are you willing to pay for each execution unit, it varies but it is around 5gwei (5x10^9) in rinkeby.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: well @DBWeinstein - Eventually it appeared i had insufficient funds. The transaction price in ETH mainnet sky rocketed. I solved it by switching to polygon

Comment: @user3059255 thanks.  I figured out my issue.  as always, it was stupidity driven. I didn’t have the address as a string.